# Issue with 9 patch buttons in Android

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to make a custom button style with a 3d look to it, but I'm having issue with the "pressed" state of the button. The button changes image properly, but the text stays still, which makes it look like the text is actually sliding upwards on press.

[image: expected vs reality]

(Red lines added to show the cancel button's baseline)

XML for the button view (cmdNegative is the cancel button, layDialogControl is a layout directly above the buttons)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cmdPositive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_positive"
    android:text="Accept"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layDialogControl"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cmdNegative"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

XML for the button style (button_gray is the exact same as button_green just... well... gray)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_gray" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_green_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_green_pressed" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_green" />
</selector>
```

Unpressed 9 patch:[image: unpressed 9 patch]

Pressed 9 patch:[image: pressed 9 patch]

As far as I'm understanding, setting the pixels on the right/bottom should have defined the "content area" and the text should stay in the content view, buuuuuuut that's not the case. Any ideas or pointers as to where I've messed up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding your edit I have removed, it's worth noting that downvotes are not _necessarily_ rudeness - more often they are just messages. It is ideal if someone accompanies a DV with some actionable feedback, but they are not obligated to. In general I would advise not worrying about them.

Comment: Yeah that's great and all, but regardless the question remains unanswered and will now likely never get an answer because it will get buried in any search results. Reasons don't matter when the end result is the same.

Comment: The end result for the community is different, though - if we propagate the untruth that downvotes are always insults, more SO users will perceive them as a hostile act, when that may not have been the voter's intention.

Comment: It's been a couple of weeks on this - are you still looking for an answer? I might be able to wave a magic wand, if so... `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood 9-patch images.  The stretchable areas (top and left sides) that you define will stretch according to your layout definition.  The content area, right and bottom parts defined will set the limits for your content similar to like specifying a rectangle/square of area where your content will be kept.  Your image for the accept button(pressed) will not stretch when clicked, thus whatever your image looks like is showing.

Furthermore, if your image has the text in it then there is no point of having a content area.  If your button image has text defined then you can solve your problem by re-defining your content area.  In other words on the pressed-state you are just substituting an image which had the correct content area region so it looks like it has been stretched on click but it is actually just another image.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the issue. The press button's 9-patch is rendering properly it's not just getting scaled up, and there is no text in the image files (as this would require a different image for every button that get's made). I do have a content area set for both 9-patches (you can see there are black pixels on the right and bottom), but issue is that the content area is not being used, it's just drawing the text centered regardless of what 9-patch I use. If I've incorrectly set the content area, please explain how.

Comment: I re-read your comment, and now I think you're saying there's something wrong with my selector/how I've set up the style, but again, if I've done it wrong please explain how.